# Rails has_one :through - undefined method create_

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `create_postconversation' for #<Post...>
```

...originating from this line:

**posts_controller.rb**

```
@postconversation = @post.create_postconversation
```

What am I doing wrong?

**post.rb**

```
has_one :postconvo, foreign_key: "post_id", dependent: :destroy
has_one :postconversation,  through: :postconvo,
                            class_name: "Conversation",
                            source: :conversation
```

**postconvo.rb**

```
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :conversation

validates :post_id, presence: true
validates :conversation_id, presence: true
```

**conversation.rb**

```
has_one :postconvo, foreign_key: "conversation_id", dependent: :destroy
has_one :post, through: :postconvo, source: :post
```

Comment: where is the method `create_postconversation` your using in `@post.create_postconversation` defined?

Comment: @RockwellRice I believe they're using the `create_association` method provided by has_one. The documentation for it is here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference

Comment: Yes, exactly, it's the method to create a has_one association.